# Exception while running SMO on powershell 2.0

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I am trying generate SQL Server Table Scripts of a database. I am using PowerShell v2 and SMO ON Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2.

Here is my sample code...

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string[]]$server,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string[]]$user,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string[]]$password,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string[]]$database,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string[]]$output_path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string[]]$DBSchema
)
$schema             = $dbSchema
$table_path         = "$output_path\"+$schema+"\"+$database+"\Table\"
$storedProcs_path   = "$output_path\"+$schema+"\"+$database+"\StoredProcedure\"
$views_path         = "$output_path\"+$schema+"\"+$database+"\View\"
$udfs_path          = "$output_path\"+$schema+"\"+$database+"\UserDefinedFunction\"
$textCatalog_path   = "$output_path\"+$schema+"\"+$database+"\FullTextCatalog\"
$udtts_path         = "$output_path\"+$schema+"\"+$database+"\UserDefinedTableTypes\"

$db         = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database")
$tbl        = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Table")
$scripter   = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Scripter") ($server)

# Get the database and table objects
$db = $srv.Databases[$database]

$tbl            = $db.tables | Where-object { $_.schema -eq $schema  -and -not $_.IsSystemObject } 

function CopyObjectsToFiles($objects, $outDir) {

    if (-not (Test-Path $outDir)) {
        [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($outDir)
    }

    foreach ($o in $objects) { 

        if ($o -ne $null) {

            $schemaPrefix = ""

            if ($o.Schema -ne $null -and $o.Schema -ne "") {
                $schemaPrefix = $o.Schema + "."
            }

            $scripter.Options.FileName = $outDir + $schemaPrefix + $o.Name + ".sql"
            Write-Host "Writing " $scripter.Options.FileName
            $scripter.EnumScript($o)
        }
    }
}

CopyObjectsToFiles $tbl $table_path
```

I don't know where I am getting wrong.

Is there any problem with EnumScript in Powershell 2.0?

[image]

I have tried to capture exception message. Here are the screens

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like its failing to connect to the server, have you checked what the variable $tbl contains?

Comment: Yes. It contains all the tables within the DB

Comment: Sorry I did't mention. I am able to run above code  on Powershell 3.0 (windows 7)

Comment: Are the versions of SMO the same as the location where it works?

Comment: Also try putting a try/catch around the method call to display the whole execption stack - it might help...

Comment: My doubt is that, can I run SMO Scripter on Powershell V2 ????? Why it is running on Win 7 and not on Win 2008 Server ???

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work - have you tried catching the exception.  Also try being explicit about the new-object creation: New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Scripter -ArgumentList $server

Comment: You can definitely run SMO on PowerShell 2.0

Comment: Agree with @MikeShepard, I've just tried it

Comment: Run PowerShell in V2.0 mode on the Win7 machine so we can rule out PowerShell as the culprit.  You can do this by running `powershell -version 2` from a command prompt.

Comment: Surprisingly.. I am able to run Script from **powershell -version 2** in my win 7 ... What to do..????